# Arithmetic problems with java longs

Tags: java, math, floating-point, arithmetic-expressions

I have two equations: `x * x - D * y * y = 1` and `x = sqrt(1 + D * y * y)`.
Both are algebraic manipulations of the other.

Given D, I need to solve for the smallest integer value of x so that y is also an integer. I loop through possible y values, plug them into the second equation and test if x is an integer. If it is, I return x.

The problem I have is when x, y, and D are plugged into the 1st equation, it does not equal 1.

These are some problematic values:

```
1. x=335159612 y=42912791 D=61
2. x=372326272 y=35662389 D=109
```

My intuition is that java's `Math.sqrt` method does not calculate such a small decimal, however `BigDecimal` does not have a square root method.

Is my math just wrong? If not, what can I do to accurately calculate x and y?

Edit: Here is the root of the problem along with the method that tests if a double is a a natural number.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    long x = 335159612, D = 61, y = 42912791;
    System.out.println(Math.sqrt(D * y * y + 2)); // 3.35159612E8
    System.out.println(x * x - D * y * y); // 3
}

public static boolean isNatural(double d){
    return d == (int)d;
}
```

Comment: Show us the code you are using to test for an integer.

Comment: For one thing, `sqrt(61 * 42912791 * 42912791)` [is not an integer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(61+*+42912791+*+42912791)). If you're storing the result of the sqrt into a long then of course it'll look like a whole number.

Comment: In fact show us the code, all of it, or as much as is necessary to exhibit the problem. For example if you're trying to calculate `42912791 * 42912791` in integers the result will overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with precisions in 'double'.

As per IEEE 754-1985 the double precision provides 16 digits (15,9 to be absolutely precise).

E.g. 
a) SQRT(112331965515990542) is

```
335159611.99999999701634694576505237017910
```

Which, when converted into double, gives 3.3515961199999999E8

b) SQRT(112331965515990543)

```
335159611.99999999850817347288252618840968
```

Which, when converted into double, gives 3.3515961199999999E8.
So, as per IEEE 754-1985 definition, those values are equal.
Apparently, any further logical/mathematical checks will be, generally speaking, inaccurate.

To overcome this limitation I recommend BigMath package from [www.javasoft.ch](http://www.javasoft.ch/)

```
import ch.javasoft.math.BigMath;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long D = 61L, y = 42912791L;
        double a = Math.sqrt(D * y * y + 1);
        double b = Math.sqrt(D * y * y + 2);
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(a == b);

        BigDecimal bda = BigMath.sqrt(new BigDecimal(D * y * y + 1), 32);
        BigDecimal bdb = BigMath.sqrt(new BigDecimal(D * y * y + 2), 32);
        System.out.println(bda.toString());
        System.out.println(bdb.toString());
        System.out.println(bda.equals(bdb));
    }
}
```

Result:

```
3.35159612E8
3.35159612E8
true
335159611.99999999701634694576505237017910
335159611.99999999850817347288252618840968
false
```

---

P.s. to completely ruin your faith in standard Java maths try this:

```
System.out.println(0.9200000000000002);
System.out.println(0.9200000000000001);
```

You will see:

```
0.9200000000000002
0.9200000000000002
```

Answer (score 1):

This kind of Diophantine's equations is known as Pell's equations.
[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell's_equation).
[Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PellEquation.html).

Both links contain clues - how to solve this equation using continued fractions.

I think it would be nice to apply some math instead of brutforce/

Answer (score 0):

If sqrt is the issue, use the first equation instead. If x is an integer, x^2 will also be an integer; if x is not an integer, then x^2 would also not be an integer, as long as you are using BigDecimals with sufficient scale for your math and not doubles.